# Netbeans Error in JavaEE project

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I created javaEE project on WinXP and now i trying to open it in another PC having Win7 and then i run it i got an error

> Could not find file C:\Program Files\Sun\JavaDB\lib\derbyclient.jar to copy.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

But i havent such directory and javadb located here

> C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.0.1\javadb

How can i fix it? thx

Answer (score 1):

Are you running it from Netbeans? If yes, are you able to run the program from command prompt? Did you set your [classpath](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-classpath) correctly?