# Java Netbeans libs.email.classpath not found warning

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation

While compiling my application with Netbeans IDE I got a warning like:

```
Could not find file Y:\7th sem\2\checking\${libs.email.classpath} to copy.
BUILD FAILED
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465814/netbeans-error-in-javaee-project).

Answer (score 0):

check your classpath in NetBeans project and don't use spaces in file location path, Java don't like it. If you're using Ant, check your build.xml file.